# What's the MAXIMUM number of records and tables MYSQL supports?

Tags: sql, mysql

What's the MAXIMUM number of records and tables MYSQL supports? I've just seen a figure of 60,000 tables and 5 billion records but i'm sure it much more than that now? Does anyone know? Also love to see a comparison with other RDBMS's out there?

Thank you in advance ;-)

Comment: This the sort of thing which varies across versions of a product and also, in the case of MySQL, according to storage engine.

Answer (score 3):

Um, not to be impolite, but have you used Google and found the [Wikipedia article about the comparison of RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems)?

Comment: +1 There's no harm in people asking questions with answers easily found elsewhere on SO - it just means the answer is now also available here!

Answer (score 1):

Look there

[Maximum number of records in a MySQL database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716232/maximum-number-of-records-in-a-mysql-database-table)

> mysql int types can do quite a few rows:
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html
>
> unsigned int largest value is 4,294,967,295 unsigned bigint largest
>   value is 18,446,744,073,709,551,615

and there :

http://www.dbforums.com/mysql/378480-max-number-tables-mysql-database.html

> The number of tablespaces will again be limited by your operating
>   system. Using NTFS on NT, the limit is 4,294,967,295. I imagine UNIX
>   will be limited by the number of inodes. However, before reaching the
>   physical limit of files you wil probably run into an issue with the
>   maximum number of 'open' files allowed.

My two first hit in google ;-)