# Mysql maximum rows

Tags: mysql, database

I am looking to create a database that will essentially have just a few tables, but with the potential for millions of rows.

Let's say the site is an image sharing website.  I will have one table with a single primary key, and about 5 fields (id, view_order, user_id, image_file, date_uploaded).

I will have a second table that will count votes (id, image_id, time_voted)

Very simple.

Can MySQL easily handle a database where the first table may have 1-2 billion rows, and the second table, potentially 100's of billions of rows?

I don't need to do any searching, just simple counting of votes, and a lookup of an image based on the id of the image on the first table.

I'm not a database expert, so please forgive my terminology.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: what are the columns that define their relationship?

Comment: "easily handle" a terarow table?  No.  No software product can do that.

Comment: votes.image_id -> images.id

Comment: Easily? No. Possible? Yes. Open up your browser and start doing research on how Tumblr and Twitter handled their massive data storage requirements.

Comment: Thanks @Perception, I have been doing research, but much of it is either centered on case studies where there are hundreds of tables and complex joins, massive amounts of venture capital, etc...

I look at a site like IMGUR and until it really took off, it was a one man shop - like me, and I'm hoping that if my site becomes anywhere near as popular as IMGUR or has to do anywhere near the amount of storage I'm discussing above, I'll have some revenue to ramp things up

Comment: @HighParkCoder - the only advise I can give is to design small, scale big. And keep your design flexible enough to change if needed (because you will almost certainly have too). Also, don't expect a one-size fits all solution to handling big data (it doesn't exist). Facebook had to actually reengineer MySQL sharding to get it working the way they needed. Expensive work!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On a 32-bit system, using an unsigned int you can have about 4 billion records. Use big int and/or a 64-bit system, it's virtually unlimited. Facebook uses MySQL as their backend, the problem isn't the number of records, it's performance. MySQL can handle hundreds of millions of rows and have very good performance.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I don't imagine doing any kind of complex queries, just along the lines of:
1) When the view page is requested, do a lookup by image id to figure out what image to show
2) When the image is viewed, do a count of how many votes for that image are in the votes table, and display
3) If an image is voted on, add a record to the votes table

Comment: Long term you should store #2 in a cache, like memcache. When #3 happens, update the cached value.

Answer (score 1):

Some more information for you to digest !

[Maximum number of records in a MySQL database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716232/maximum-number-of-records-in-a-mysql-database-table)

Thanks,
Naval