# What to do if my mysql database total rows exceeds 65535?

Tags: mysql, database

What to do if my mysql database table total rows exceeds 65535?What type of database can i use inorder to store more data?

Comment: MySQL doesn't limit the number of rows to 65535. There's a limit on _row size_ of 65535.

Comment: This is no builtin limit of MySQL. You can store millions of rows in just one table.

Comment: how much rows a single table can hold?

Comment: @user1673591 see this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-size-limit.html

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2716470/535871) for details on how many rows you can have. It depends on your table engine. As @D-side points out, there are also limits on the total size of the table (independent of the number of rows).

Comment: I didn't downvote (although I'm thinking about it), but my guess is that it is because the question "does not show any research effort". (Hover over the downvote arrow to see a brief summary of downvoting reasons.) All the info posted here is easily found by searching the web for "mysql 65535". Also, the comment thread has completely changed the question, which makes your question either "unclear" or "not useful" (other criterion for downvoting).

Comment: @user1673591 First of all, this question contains incorrect information, and thus is misleading. Moreover, you didn't supply any information of what you've found youself before posting a question, you could have found the link I've given in like **10 seconds**. We solve questions collaboratively and we expect you to collaborate as well, since it's your question.

Comment: @user1673591, are you confusing the terms *rows* and *columns*?

Comment: check Question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716232/maximum-number-of-records-in-a-mysql-database-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation says

`The effective maximum table size for MySQL databases is usually determined by operating system constraints on file sizes, not by MySQL internal limits.`

As @ D-side  points out the number of rows depends on the engines used.

For example 
`In InnoDB, with a limit on table size of 64 terabytes and a MySQL row-size limit of 65,535 there can be 1,073,741,824 rows.`

Please check [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-size-limit.html)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716232/maximum-number-of-records-in-a-mysql-database-table/2716470#2716470)for more details..Hope it helps

Comment: Maximum table size and maximum number of rows are two different things.