# In Mysql Database Table, Which search faster?(string or int)

Tags: mysql

In Mysql Database Table, Which search faster?

1- Search in **String** Columns
2- Search in **Number** Rows

1- Example Data
`column_string include <long string> <type: text>:
sdf,sdfa,sdfaf,sfdsdf,sdfsg,sfdfg,sdfe,qwer,qwe,rt,45dg,sf,34wer,we3,q3e,sdf,wersg,sg,sfgef,e,f,w,s,w,sdf,sd,w,sdf,sg,fg,sdfa,sdfaf,sfdsdf,sdfsg,sfdfg,sdfe,qwer,qwe,rt,45dg,sf,34wer,we3,q3e,sdf,wersg,sg,sfgef,e,f,w,s,w,sdf,sd,w,sdf,sg,fg,sdfa,sdfaf,sfdsdf,sdfsg,sfdfg,sdfe,qwer,iopiop,rt,45dg,sf,34wer,we3,q3e,sdf,wersg,sg,sfgef,e,f,w,s,w,ioipi,sd,w,sdf,sg,fg,sdfa,sdfaf,sfdsdf,sdfsg,sfdfg,sdfe,qwer,qwe,rt,45dg,sf,34wer,asdfsdf,q3e,sdf,wersg,sg,sfgef,e,f,w,s,w,sdf,sd,w,sdf,sg,fg,sdfa,sdfaf,sfdsdf,sdfsg,sfdfg,sdfe,qwer,qwe,rt,45dg,sf,34wer,we3,q3e,sdf,wersg,sg,sfgef,e,f,w,s,w,sdf,sd,w,sdf,sg,fg,sdfa,sdfaf,sfdsdf,sdfsg,sfdfg,sdfe,qwer,qwe,rt,45dg,sf,34wer,we3,q3e,sdf,wersg,sg,sfgef,e,f,w,s,w,sdf,sd,w,sdf,sg,fg,.....`

2- Example Data
`tbl row 1 --> id: 1
tbl row 2 --> id: 2
.
.
tbl row 95100984612346 --> id: 95100984612346`

1- Example Query:
`select column_string(type=text) from tbl where column_string.include("mystring")`

2- Example Query:
`select id from tbl where id == 25100984612346`

Which search faster?

Comment: the one with index is faster.

Comment: @YOU thnks, What is the maximum number of rows to the table? (bigInt) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716232/maximum-number-of-records-in-a-mysql-database-table

Answer (score 1):

in MySQL database searching will be faster with numeric field having primary key.