# Why so many collisions with the MariaDB 10.2 RAND() function?

Tags: mysql, sql, random, mariadb

Note: Running MariaDB 10.2.27 on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.

I wanted to generate random integers for use in MariaDB so I have been experimenting with the MariaDB RAND() function. Either my expectations & understanding are way off base (definitely possible!) or the MariaDB RAND() function is not very random.

Using a BIGINT(20) column I wanted to generate random integers up to 16 digits in length, so I used this SQL: `FLOOR(RAND()*9999999999999999)+1)`. The exact SQL I use, in a loop is:

`INSERT INTO rnd_test VALUES (FLOOR(RAND()*9999999999999999)+1);`

Table rnd_test has a single column which is a BIGINT(20) and is the primary ID.

With a pool of 10^16 numbers and considering the Birthday Paradox I would expect about a 50% chance of a collision after 10^8 numbers generated. Obviously there is some variance to this but every time I run the insert loop I start seeing collisions almost immediately and then repeating every 2000 or 3000 generated numbers, sometimes more often. After ~50,000 randoms have been generated I'm seeing collisions every few hundred numbers.

Thinking that maybe my understanding was wildly incorrect I adjusted my looping vb.net code to generate the random locally and then insert that into the MariaDB table. I define a new System.Random at the top of the routine and then use this to generate random numbers:

`Dim r As Long = CLng(Math.Floor(rNum.NextDouble() * 9999999999999999)) + 1`

Generally this works much better but still not quite as well as I would expect. It will usually run for about 100,000 iterations before a collision occurs, and then after that there seems to be one or two collisions per 10,000 randoms generated. Sometimes a batch of 10,000 will go by without any collisions at all.

So, why is the MariaDB RAND() function performing so poorly compared to the vb.net function?

Comment: I would recommend to use uuid instead

Comment: Agreed, and that is what I have done until now when I needed random IDs. Unfortunately in this case I do not have that option. I specifically need random integers.

Comment: `rand()` produces a double which only has 16 digits of precision.  That would definitely affect the collision rate.  You should be able to do what you want with two calls to `rand()`.

Comment: @Ian You could convert a uuid *to* a (big) integer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, that has worked beautifully. Made a quick change to the code and have now generated over 350,000 randoms with no collisions at all. Thank you!!

Comment: Another option: get uuid, then sha1 or md5 of uuid, cut it at 64 bits (first 16 characters), convert to 64 bit integer. should be excellent quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further experiments with 5.6's RAND indicate that it is good to only 30 bits.  That is it has only about one billion distinct values.

File a bug with bugs.mysql.com and/or MariaDB.

30 bits is good enough for most applications.  Of those applications for which it is not good enough, most people won't notice its wimpiness.

`FLOAT` has 24 bits of precision; `DOUBLE` has 53.  So 30 needs `DOUBLE`, but fails to fill it up.

Comment: Spot on, it is exactly 30 bits in MariaDB . implementation uses integer arithmetic  https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.5/mysys/my_rnd.c#L33