# How to create a query commend in Libre Office in Debian?

Tags: jquery, debian, mysql-python, libreoffice

I have got a database in MySqlDB, and I am using MariaDB 10.1.
My Debian version is 9.1.

I already connected this mysql database to the Libre Office with these parameters:

```
host='localhost',
user='root',
passwd='1234',
db='database1"
```

In this way I get the all information about the selected table (in this database1, I have got 2 datatable), but there is a row limit in Excel and in Libre Office too.

Thats why I want to create a "button" in the Libre Office which one I can list, I can do a query what dataes need for me. For example I want see the dataes where name is = "Adam". Is it real to do this? If yes, how I have to start it?

Comment: It sounds like you are using LibreOffice Calc.  Why not use LibreOffice Base directly, where there is no row limit, and it is easy to set up queries such as where name = 'Adam`.  To start it, if you already have an ODB file, then open it; otherwise, go to to File -> New -> Database.

Comment: In the LibreOffice Base there isn't any row limit? Is it real?
My sql database is get new information in every hour, how can I solve it to keep connect to the new dataes and see it?

Comment: How much data is needed -- billions of rows?  For limits on MySQL tables, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2716470/5100564.  To see new data, click Refresh in LibreOffice Base.  "Is it real" -- I do not know what you mean by this.

Comment: 5 millions rows/ year maybe, but my goal is to create a button in this LibreOffice Base, and a text box where i can write for example : i want to select all "Adam" from the table.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [form](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Working_with_Forms) in LibreOffice Base, with a button and a text box.

For a tutorial, try this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z67noJLMgO4.  Disclaimer: I only watched part of the video.

What you are asking is possible; I have made similar forms before.  If you have problems, please explain in detail what you have done so far and we can help.

Comment: Thank you! I am watching these videos! 
My database is change in every hour, that's why I need to create a button which one I can reconnect again to this database to get informations.