# Is there 1 GB data storage space in any 1 table of MySQL?

Tags: mysql, data-storage, embedded-database, capacity, blobstorage

We have web-based app in production with thousand of users. We analyzed embedded DBs and while reading about data storage capacity of mySQL, we come across this

> Each individual table should not exceed 1 GB in size or 20 million rows

My requirement is to store BLOBS in 1 table of my mySQL DB.

If the storage capacity of mySQL is only 1 GB, then my DB will crash in production because my blobs quickly occupy 1 GB?

Comment: That seems like a limit set by the service you use for hosting your app. Consult with them.

Comment: i want to use its embedded version and i read the statement from https://support.tigertech.net/mysql-size

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you read that an individual table should not exceed 1 GB or 20 million rows. Those are definitely not size limits for MySQL tables.

See my answer in [Maximum number of records in a MySQL database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716232/maximum-number-of-records-in-a-mysql-database-table/2716470#2716470)

You will fill up your storage before you reach the maximum table size MySQL supports. In other words, there is no storage that exists today that is larger than the limit of a MySQL InnoDB table.

That said, there are *recommended* size limits. For example, if you let a table grow too large (e.g. 1TB), it will take days to do a schema change or an optimize table.

At my work, we recommend to the developers that they should keep tables under 500GB, and we warn them if it goes over 1TB. Because the larger the table gets, the harder it is to complete certain operations tasks (defragmentation, backups, restores, schema changes, etc.).

There's no specific limit or threshold, it's simply that "the bigger it is, the more time it takes."

This is true for *anything* that runs on a computer — not just MySQL and not just databases.

Comment: i read the statement from https://support.tigertech.net/mysql-size so what does this size restriction means?

Comment: It looks like it's just a policy of that hosting company, not a technical limitation of MySQL. If you need a larger scale database, then you should look for a different hosting provider.