# Is there a maximum number of rows in a MySQL (community) database table?

Tags: mysql

I have an application with a fairly simple, flat schema but the primary table could grow beyond a billion records.

Other than performance related issues, is there a limitation to the number of rows in a table?

Comment: You might want to check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-size-limit.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716232/maximum-number-of-records-in-a-mysql-database-table

Comment: *is there a limitation to the number of rows in a table?* Yes. It is defined by inner row number size (AFAIR in InnoDB it is 6 bytes - i.e. not more than 2^48 rows).

Comment: [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Clustered and Secondary Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-index-types.html): *The row ID is a 6-byte field that increases monotonically as new rows are inserted.*