# Maximum rows allowed in Mysql Innodb table

Tags: mysql

I a have a mysql table T Engine Innodb:
Structure :

```
T{  
    f1 INT(11) PK,
    f2 INT(11) Index
}
```

Now tell me how many maximum rows this table could hold?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716232/maximum-number-of-records-in-a-mysql-database-table

Comment: so, dupe of [Maximum number of records in a MySQL database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716232/maximum-number-of-records-in-a-mysql-database-table)