# Database for 100K app users (each user has 400 customer) - one table for all customers, or multiple tables: one seperate customer table for each user?

Tags: mysql, database

I am using MySQL with innodb.

My app is used by business owners (users), with primary key: `user_phone`. The app will have a maximum of 100K users. Each user will have around 400 customers, with primary key: `customer_phone`, and 10 other fields. Each user also has around 30K messages (3 fields: `subject`, `message`, `sent_datetime`) sent to those 400 customers.

So, I have 2 options:

Option 1: To make 2 tables for all `customers`, and `messages` combined in these 2 tables:

Table `Customer`:

```
user_phone  customer_phone  field1  field2  field3 .... field10
```

Primary key => `user_phone`, `customer_phone`

Total rows: 100k (users) X 400 (customers)

And

Messages:

```
user_phone  customer_phone  subject  message  sent_datetime
```

Primary key => `user_phone`, `customer_phone`, `subject`, `message`, `sent_datetime`

Total rows: 100k (users) X 30K (messages)

As you can see that the tables are only two, but it has many million rows.

Or

Option 2: I can have individual table for each user, the table name has `user_phone` number in it:

Table `customers_<user_phone>` eg. customers_888111222:

```
customer_phone  field1  field2  field3 .... field10
```

Primary key => `customer_phone`

Total rows in each table: 400 (customers)

and similarly for `messages`: Table name: `messages_<user_phone>` eg. `messages_888111222`: Total rows in each table: 30K (messages).

Total tables (2 tables for each user): 500k (for customers) + 500k (for messages) = 1 million tables but with much less rows.

So, either I can have 2 tables with 40 million of rows, or 1 million tables with some hundreds rows in each.

I have one more option, kind of a middle path: to have 50 tables: one for each state. And each state's table will have customer data of those users who belong to that state. So, there will be total 50 (customers) + 50 (messages) = 100 tables with around a million rows each.

Please suggest the correct database structure.

And what if the users increase to like 500k from initial 100k. that will increase rows to 5 times if only 2 tables are used.

Comment: Have tables as a “dimension” will cause you all sorts of pain. For example, adding users becomes a DDL operation, requiring elevated privileges on the database. Further, database engines are designed to scale table size not number of tables; with appropriate indexes 40m rows is perfectly manageable.

Comment: problem I am facing is that I can not use any class models for the tables because table name is a variable, so it can not have a class.

Comment: ok, I will use the big table, and less tables approach, instead of small table, and multiple tables.

Comment: Exactly - it’s a bad idea all round.

Comment: @BoristheSpider ok, what if the users increase to like 500k from initial 100k. that will increase rows to 5 times. what would be a "manageable" maximum index size?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2716470/2071828. Obviously at some point you’ll hit a limit. But then the answer might be to, for example move the biggest tables to a different data store; one designed for massive volume - like Cassandra. There are lots of options when you have 500k users; just don’t solve them all now or you’ll have no product for the first user!

Comment: Think 'security' — should there be any risk that UserA could ever see the data about UserB's customers?  If you use a single table, you run a serious risk of information spillover.  If you use separate tables per user, it is much harder for a single query to accidentally reveal information about another user's customers. It also becomes a problem if CustomerA wants to use different information when contacting UserA's business and UserB's business. The downside is that CustomerA will have to update each business user's database with their amended information. On the whole, though, that's safer.