# MySQL DB_ROW_ID with a table having BIGINT

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

MySQL has an internal column per row, 6 byte DB_ROW_ID. How does MySQL generate this ID for a table that has (2^64)-1 rows in it without duplicating DB_ROW_ID?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2716470/17389

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internal 6-byte id for InnoDB exists only if you don't have either

- An explicit `PRIMARY KEY`, or
- A `UNIQUE` with non-null column(s).

Anyway, there are multiple hard limits that will be hit before a table reaches (2^64)-1 rows.  Some will be hit before 2^48.

More on limits:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits